# Entity framework remove a relationship with migrations

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I am using Entity Framework 5 with migrations.  My model looks like this:

```
UserRegistration
Sessions
```

For each registration there can be many sessions.  I was having a problem with a SQL cascading delete error when trying to run migrations, so I attempted to remove the cascade delete by adding the following code:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserRegistration>()
                    .HasOptional(x => x.Sessions)
                    .WithMany()
                    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Now if you know EF you can see an error with that code.  I thought it was giving me a 1 to many relationship from UserRegistrations to Sessions, when in fact this code says "Each UserRegistration has an optional Session, each Session has many UserRegistrations".  So my 1 to many relationship was going the wrong way.  I believe this should have been the code I added.

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserRegistration>()
                    .HasMany(x => x.Sessions)
                    .WithRequired(x => x.UserRegistration)
                    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

However, when I remove the bad code (first block above), and run add-migration, I get this:

```
        public override void Up()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.UserRegistrations", "Sessions_Id", "dbo.UserRegistrationSessions");
        DropIndex("dbo.UserRegistrations", new[] { "Sessions_Id" });
        RenameColumn(table: "dbo.UserRegistrationSessions", name: "Sessions_Id", newName: "UserRegistration_Id");
    }
```

The first two lines (DropForeignKey and DropIndex) looks good, this is removing the foreign key from the UserRegistrations table.  The 3rd line, however, comes out of nowhere.  There is no Sessions_Id column in the UserRegistrationSessions table.  When I run it, I expectedly get an error:

```
Either the parameter @objname is ambiguous or the claimed @objtype (COLUMN) is wrong.
```

I'm thinking something is out of whack between my model and my modelbuilder code.  Maybe I need to try to make my model look incorrect, but match the modelbuilder code, before moving forward with the fix.

Here is the relevant code in my models:

```
public class UserRegistration
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserRegistrationSession> Sessions { get; set; }
}

public class UserRegistrationSession
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual UserRegistration UserRegistration { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Where is migrations getting it's information from?  I'm deleting any reference to Sessions_Id from the migrations files and removing the relationships entirely, then deleting the database and re-running migrations.  It then tells me my model is out of sync with my migrations, and when I run add-migration I get stuff out of nowhere.
DropIndex("dbo.UserRegistrations", new[] { "Sessions_Id" });
WTF?
That Index doesn't exist, EF!!

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an answer to the question in the comment, which is 'where is Entity Framework getting its information from'. The answer is probably the serialized version of the model in the resource file attached to the migration.

If you haven't yet deployed the migrations out in the wild, is it possible to remove the offending migration and roll back the DB to before the migration was created?